# Android Wear notification with auto focus like Gmap

Tags: java, android, wear-os, android-wear-notification

I want to create an auto-focused notification.

I have noticed that notifications have two states in Android Wear :

**FOCUSED**, the time is invisible. *When you start a navigation on Google Map, the default notification looks like this* :
[image: focused notification]

---

**NOT FOCUSED**, the time is visible :

[image: not focused notification]

You can switch from one state to another by gently dragging up or down the white notification square.

But on my app and unlike Gmap, the notification appears **not** focused.

My code on the wearable side (required for onGoing notifications) :

```
mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentText("text")
                .setOngoing(true)
                .extend(new NotificationCompat.WearableExtender()
                                .setBackground(logoBitmap)
                                .setHintHideIcon(true)
                );
        (getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)
                .notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

My notification appears unfocused like this :
[image: my-app]

I tried `setFullScreenIntent()` but without any result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally understood. Using `setVibrate()` extends the notification automatically. This is not mentioned anywhere in the doc, I just get lucky on this.